# Interpreting Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have run one of my heap file with the tool and below is the results of the Leak Hunter. Suspect 2 I guess is due to nature I am pooling so the connection are alive all the time. I cant intepret well the suspect 1 as when I press the details it give a long list of 
following details

```
java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e19670 40 92,688 
next java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e1a6a8 40 93,024 
next java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e1bda0 40 122,768 


Suspect 1.

The class "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 1,337,176 (30.93%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.ref.Finalizer" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.lang.ref.Finalizer


Suspect 2
 6 instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf58bf000" occupy 432,624 (10.01%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c54f8 - 94,864 (2.19%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c4678 - 86,600 (2.00%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c4bf8 - 85,456 (1.98%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf626c348 - 68,000 (1.57%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf626c7d0 - 68,000 (1.57%) bytes. 


Keywords
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf58bf000
```